# runOnUiThread method analog for widget?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, widget

I have a widget which needs to do some operations in another thread. It has a method which processes some data and shows the result in a TextView on the widget.
To implement this, I need to call my method in a separate thread. Then I need to include some code to the end of that method to show the results on the widget (something like `textView1.setText("my results");`.
 This has to be done in a UI thread. I want to use the method `runOnUiThread`. But it exists only for an activity. Is there an analog of this method for widget class? What can I do to use that method in my widget?

Here is my code:

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) 
{
//...
//here I need to launch a method toBeLaunchedInASeparateThread in a separate thread
}

public void toBeLaunchedInASeparateThread()
{
 // ... many operations
 int result = 0;

//here I need to launch the following line in the UI thread to follow Android guidelines
 setTextToTextView(context, "My result is " + result);
}

public static void setTextToTextView(Context context, String text)
    {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_sample);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetTextViewCard, text);
        ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(manager.getAppWidgetIds(myWidget), views);      
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blackbelt's answer is great, however you can also use `textView1.post(runnable)` and methods like that. This way you don't have to create a Handler instance, and the code will run on UI thread. AFAIK both solution will do the exactly same things.

For RemoteViews:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();//this must be ran on the UI thread.
....
mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        toBeLaunchedInASeparateThread();
    }
});
```

Comment: If I do not have `textView1` in my code explicitly, what else does have a `post(runnable)` method which will work in my case?

Comment: the whole point of a widget is that you never actually manipulates views per se, but rather only RemoteViews and view ids. Therefore, you don't have a View on which to call `post(runnable)`. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @njzk2 , could you please suggest an alternative way for me to updat widget's textView from another thread?

Comment: blackbelt's answer is the correct one. you need to read about Handlers. You can look at the handler section from this Vogella tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_handler

Comment: the code of remoteviews were added after i posted my answer, so it is as correct as it could be.

Answer (score 2):

you can use an Handler, to connect with the UI Thread and post on its queue. `Handler.post(Runnable)`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) the documentation

Comment: What is `Handler` in my case? Should I use something from my code, or I need to create somehow a new `Handler`?

Comment: I have posted my code above. Could you please have a look and say where and what should I put?